# Button at Bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

Im not very good in creating android layouts so I am not able to align the button to the bottom in the MainView.

Picture:

[image]

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical">


    <ListView android:id="@+id/lv_pizza" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/bt_add" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="hinzufügen"></Button>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Please help

Comment: Do you need that realtiveLayout? Or put it for problem solving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for a linear layout, note the `layout_weight` `1` on the list -- that's what pushes the button to the bottom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/lv_pizza"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/bt_add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hinzufügen" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This then looks like this in the UI editor:

[image]

Comment: Also, don't ever set [`layout_height="wrap_content"` on a `ListView`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&feature=player_detailpage#t=2456s)

Comment: ... and [never put a `ListView` into a `ScrollView`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70#t=2562s) either.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can set like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"    android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical">


<ListView android:id="@+id/lv_pizza" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_above="@+id/bt_add" android:layout_height="fill_parent" ></ListView>

<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/bt_add" 
 android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="hinzufügen"></Button>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't result in the desired layout unless you replace `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. Otherwise a nice alternative to `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `RelativeLayout` will push the button to bottom of the screen...

Answer (score 0):

Use a layout_weight for the components inside the LinearLayout.  If the ListView has a weight of 1.0, it should push the button to the bottom.  I've done this with a ScrollLayout and it works well, allowing the component inside the scroll layout to actually scroll.  You could put your ListView into a ScrollLayout to let it grow beyond the visible size.

Also, the second relativelayout also isn't necessary as it doesn't add anything.

Comment: [Don't put a `ListView` into a `ScrollView`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70#t=2562s) -- it will make a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a marginTop in the Button until the bottom or change the layout to relative and set the position.